# how to convert the visible part of a data buffer to integer without ValueError

Tags: python

I have a data buffer called `data` which is shown in the debugger as `004`. But `len(data)` is `7`. At least it ends with linefeed and carriage return also.

`__buildin__.int(data)` aborts with error message `ValueError: null byte in argument for int()`.

How should I get my integer value `4` out of the string?

---

EDIT: repr(data) results to `004\\x00^\\r\\n`

Comment: Try `print repr(data)` to show what all the bytes are.

Comment: Better yet, try `for c in data: print ord(c)`.

Comment: Did you try to strip it ? Might be the linefeed and carriage return. Also you can check https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm

Comment: @debzsud: I believe that `int()` can "digest" white spaces, etc, so it's gotta be some other character in there. Also, `null byte in argument for int()` indicates that there's probably a 0 character in that string.

Comment: strip, rstrip and splitlines don't help either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print the integer values of the characters in the input string:

```
for c in data:
    print ord(c)
```

Then you'll see that there is one or more null (0) characters in it.

So simply remove these characters from the input string before converting it to an integer:

```
data = data.replace(chr(0),'')
```

Note that `print data` by itself will not "reveal" these characters.

---

UPDATE:

To be on the safe side, you can remove any non-digit character from the input string.

Alternatively, you can reconstruct the input string using only the digit characters:

```
data = ''.join(c for c in data if c.isdigit())
```

Comment: This gives me another error message: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '004\\\r\n'

Comment: Well, you should get the hang of it by now. Just remove every non-digit character from your string. Something like `data = ''.join(c for c in data if c.isdigit())`.

Comment: Well done, barak manos, this works like a charme. Thanks a lot!